# adding three.js to phoenix live view project

Tags: javascript, three.js, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I'm trying to add three.js as a dependency to my Phoenix Project.

At the moment, I've vendored a minified three.js version in `/assets/vendor/three.min.js`

From there I added the following to my app.js:

```
import * as THREE from "../vendor/three.min.js";

window.THREE = THREE;

let Hooks = {};
Hooks.ThreeInit = {
  mounted() {
    if (this.el.dataset.initialized === "false") {
      this.initThreeScene();
      this.el.dataset.initialized = "true";
    }
  },
  initThreeScene() {
    // Initialize your three.js scene here, using `THREE` object.
    // For example:
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.el.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.z = 5;

    const animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    animate();
  }
};

// other alpine stuff here

let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live", Socket, {
  params: {_csrf_token: csrfToken},
  hooks: Hooks,
  dom: {
    onBeforeElUpdated(from, to) {
      if (from._x_dataStack) {
        window.Alpine.clone(from, to)
      }
    }
  }
})

// connect if there are any LiveViews on the page
liveSocket.connect()
```

The live view I am trying to render the 3D cube over is as follows:

```
defmodule PortfolioWeb.ThreeJSLive do
  use Phoenix.LiveView

  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end



  def render(assigns) do
    ~L"""
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <div id="three-container" phx-hook="ThreeInit"></div>
    """
  end
end
```

At the moment, the only thing that renders is the `Hello World`

Any help in figuring out what the issue is would be greatly appreciated <3

Comment: Does javascript console in DevTools show anything?

Comment: I am not sure what "I've vendored a minified three.js version" means... but why would you be trying to import from a minified version?

Comment: @2pha vendoring is the recommended (as far as I have been told) way the phx live view framework handles js deps due to npm's unreliability with the framework. 

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/installation.html#progress-animation

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Nothing in the console DevTools.